# Cloud Firestore Sub-Collection on a Document not Creating

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the following code to create a document under users collection. Then under that document tags sub-collection with multiple documents. When this code executes the user document is created but the sub-collection is not created. Why?

```dart
final userDoc = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid);

final batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();

batch.set(userDoc, {'id': uid, 'name': 'John Doe'});

for (var tag in tagsList) {
  final tagDoc = userDoc.collection('tags').doc();
  batch.set(tagDoc, {'id': tagDoc.id, 'value': tag});
}

await batch.commit();
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen here?  We can't see the value of `tagsList` so we don't know if or how many documents would result from running this.  For all we know, it could be an empty list, meaning no subcollection documents would be created.

Comment: Thanks for your comment the list was empty. I solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tagsList` was an empty list. Doug Stevenson pointed that out and it solved the issue.